# Generating symetrical table with unique numbers

Tags: r

I need to generate a table similar to this one:

```
    18  21  16  40  19  30
18      39  34  58  37  48
21          37  61  40  51
16              56  35  46
40                  59  70
19                      49
30
```

The numbers in the first column and row are the same sequence of numbers so finally the table would be symmetrical. What I need is to get a 10x10 table, all with unique numbers so nothing repeats, as I need these as unique identifiers later. This is more of a mathematical problem rather than programming.

Edit (primes):

```
    2   3   5   7   11  13  17  19  23  29
2       5   7   9   13  15  19  21  25  31
3           8   10  14  16  20  22  26  32
5               12  16  18  22  24  28  34
7                   18  20  24  26  30  36
11                      24  28  30  34  40
13                          30  32  36  42
17                              36  40  46
19                                  42  48
23                                      52
29
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: It is not at all clear what you want here. Are you just asking how to generate random numbers?

Comment: unique numbers rather than random

Comment: Well, `1:45` would be unique... Is that all you want?

Comment: if you put `1:45` in the first row and column, add them, then you wouldn't get all unique numbers

Comment: Maybe I see; you want the lowest-valued set of 10 whole numbers such that the sum of each number and every other number will yield a unique value. Is that right? This may belong on math.SE instead of here.

Comment: Yes that is it. I just realized it might have been better in the math.SE. But demonstrating how this can be done in R would be helpful.

Comment: How to do it in R is trivial. The issue is how to get the marginal numbers. I don't know that they would be the smallest set, but for a quick solution you could use the 1st 10 primes [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_numbers).

Comment: You get quite a few repeats with the first 10 primes (added to question)

Comment: So you do... sorry about that. They would be unique if they were multiplied, but you want summed. I didn't think far enough ahead. At any rate, someone on math.SE can solve this for you & coding it in R will be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is *a* solution: make your vector powers of ten.

```
> n=10
> v=10^(1:n)
> v
 [1] 1e+01 1e+02 1e+03 1e+04 1e+05 1e+06 1e+07 1e+08 1e+09 1e+10
> m=outer(v,v,"+")

>  m[which(upper.tri(m))]
 [1]         110        1010        1100       10010       10100       11000
 [7]      100010      100100      101000      110000     1000010     1000100
[13]     1001000     1010000     1100000    10000010    10000100    10001000
[19]    10010000    10100000    11000000   100000010   100000100   100001000
[25]   100010000   100100000   101000000   110000000  1000000010  1000000100
[31]  1000001000  1000010000  1000100000  1001000000  1010000000  1100000000
[37] 10000000010 10000000100 10000001000 10000010000 10000100000 10001000000
[43] 10010000000 10100000000 11000000000
> length(unique(m[which(upper.tri(m))])

[1] 45
```

Comment: Or powers of any integer, for that matter. Takes advantage of the unique `n`-ary representation of numbers.